# Unregister and Register XLL in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xll, xlw

I have a sheet that when loaded gets passed a path to a XLL which it loads.  I need a VBA macro that can unregister that XLL and register a new one.  I know how to register a new XLL.  How can I unregister the original XLL?
I found this code :

```
 Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "UNREGISTER(""ADDIN.xll"")"
```

But this neither removes the original function names (though it does seem to make them unusable) not does it add the new XLL.  The DLL is created with c++\XLW so I have access to this code as well if it can help.
Thanks, Stan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unregister a XLL in Excel (VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616732/unregister-a-xll-in-excel-vba)